# Hide child divs in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

So I have a string of Jquery stuff and I'm not sure why one part isn't working.

I have a structure like this

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <span class="UnlikelyHeader"> Title Here</span>
    <div id="unlikely">
        <div class="blah"></div>
        <div class="blah"></div>
        <div class="blah"></div>
    </div>
```

Its my goal to make the div "Unlikely" hidden by default, and to use a slide toggle when you click on the span.  Here's what I have for code thus far (Note, the hidden / odd/ even are the working implementation of this)

```
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            jQuery(".Hidden").hide();
            jQuery("#Unlikely.hide()");
            jQuery(".Even").click(function()
            {
                jQuery(this).next(".Hidden").slideToggle(500);
            });
            jQuery(".Odd").click(function()
            {
                jQuery(this).next(".Hidden").slideToggle(500);
            });
            jQuery(".UnlikelyHeader").click(function()
            {
                jQuery(this).next("#Unlikely").slideToggle(500);
            });
        });
```

Also note: I've tried using #Unlikely.children().hide() and other methods to hide the stuff that I don't want displayed by default.

Comment: There is a syntax error here: `jQuery("#Unlikely.hide()");`. Should be `jQuery("#Unlikely").hide();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a big fan of doing this instead -

```
$('.UnlikelyHeader').click(function() {
 $('#unlikely').slideDown(500);   
});
```

and giving it the property of `display:none` in the CSS.

**Working Example** - http://jsfiddle.net/ne7MU/ (without toggle)
http://jsfiddle.net/ne7MU/1/ (with toggle)

Hope my interpretation is correct....

Comment: While I love the slide-down effect, I want to have the ability to toggle on clicking again, which is a chore with slidedown.

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick:

```
jQuery("#unlikely").hide();
```

You can also hide it right from the get go like this:

```
<div id="unlikely" style="display:none">
```

Answer (score 2):

for starters:

```
jQuery("#Unlikely.hide()");
```

should be

```
jQuery("#unlikely").hide();
```

-edit-
also, your case is wrong on your toggle.  you have a lowercase 'u' in the html and uppercase in the javascript:

```
jQuery(this).next("#Unlikely").slideToggle(500);
```

Answer (score 2):

FYI "$" is the shorthand version of "jQuery" and is easier to read.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".Hidden").hide();
        $("#unlikely").hide(); <-------- You had your hide() method inside of the
        $(".Even").click(function()  --- selector and Unlikely should be unlikely
        {
            $(this).next(".Hidden").slideToggle(500);
        });
        $(".Odd").click(function()
        {
            $(this).next(".Hidden").slideToggle(500);
        });
        $(".UnlikelyHeader").click(function()
        {
            $(this).next("#unlikely").slideToggle(500); <---- changed Unlikely to
        });                                              ---- unlikely   
    });
```